# Implement Multithread application to speed-up querying time with JDBC?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, performance, jdbc

The facturation application I'm working needs to speed-up. I want to improve the time by dividing the work using Multithread, but the app heavyly relies in a Oracle Database and was designed to make several queries to get the information it neeeds and then performes the update statements to make the facturation each user.

The question is, will a Multithread solution will make it faster? If so, how can I implement it? Can you point me to some resources to read about the subject? And if not, then how can I make the app faster?

Comment: Do the queries build up on each other?

Comment: What is 'facturation'?

Comment: @EJP In dutch the word "facturatie" or "factureren" means invoicing, maybe it is the same.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks. I should have known that, with a Nederlandse vrouw and Kramers Engels Woorden Boek in the house :-|

Comment: You're most probably not doing it properly. Check prepared statements and batch updates first. Look if your CPU is running all the time or just waiting. Add some details to you question. `+++` Multithreading can help, but there are usually many *simpler* optimizations proving more gain.

Answer (score 0):

for your invoicing application, there are many different ways to make it run faster.  for example:

- use a database connection pooling (for example HikariCP) and send queries to the database using multiple threads
- configure your Database to use a master/slave replication, so you can send some queries to the slave (to speed up responses from the database)
- make sure that your tables have correct indexes and that each query is indeed using those indexes (use some SQL query analyzer tool)
- create specific views/tables for reporting (queries on those views/tables should be a lot faster than doing queries on multiple tables)
- use an in-memory database (like Redis) to store some of the results (if you use that same information in multiple reports)
- run your invoicing application in a separate computer (or virtual machine), to make sure that other processes in the same computer are not the reason for the delays that you are experiencing.